# netbeans chrome "Confirm Form Resubmission"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, netbeans-8

I am using NetBeans8 + Chrome. It was working perfectly.
Suddenly, chrome starts displaying "Confirm Form Resubmission...".

How disable this pop-up. It's a real problem for development.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome -disable-prompt-on-repost &

fixed the problem. But still looking how to disable it from chrome or maybe NetBeans.